# Zip file to verify if not modified

Tags: zip, checksum

I want to `zip` *source code* of my application and provide it to my client. I want to somehow assign to it an id or whatever which would describe the status of zipped files in official agreement between me and my client. I am not sure but i think there is something called `checksum`. Is that `checksum` something that will not change until someone would change anything inside the `zip package`? Therefore once files are zipped can i use such `checksum` id and put it into my agreement with customer or? If that's the case what should i do once i zipp the files and how to get such id? Thanks in advance for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On macOS in the terminal you can run the following to get the SHA-256 checksum of your ZIP archive:

```
shasum -a 256 myzipfile.zip
```

The checksum of the ZIP archive can the be checked/generated on any system (each system with their own method) and if it matches with the one you generated it means the file wasn't modified.

Comment: Is it like when i compress the file let's say on mac to the zip package file will it be having already the checksum? If so then how do i know which type of checksum (SHA or whatever?) it uses and for instance and if i understand well if i send that zip package on other machine or share in dropbox then if someone download it example to windows system the checksum should be same correct (and how to check it) ?

Comment: @Aroe - What? What type of checksum you want to calculate and provide to your client is completely up to you. A SHA256 checksum accomplishes exactly what you want.

Comment: @Arie again, I think you don't understand what the idea of a checksum is. A checksum isn't "added"/"attached" to a file, it's a mathematical calculation that can be calculated from your file and can not be recreated without having the same exact file. So you run the command above and get the SHA-256 checksum for the file and list it in your documentation. Then the receiver of the file (or anyone later) runs a SHA-256 checksum on their machine and if they get the same hash as you get then it's evidence that the file wasn't modified in any way.

Comment: @YisroelTech and what is the command to check checksum once after I execute your creation command? And also doesn’t matter on  which operating system checksum will be checked it will show the one I’ve Created?

Comment: You're not 'creating' the checksum, as such, you're 'checking' it. Imagine you have a closed box of plastic numbers, with a window to see what's in it. You add them up & write the total on the outside. Anyone else can see through the window & add up to the same total. If any of the numbers are changed in the box, the total will be wrong. [Massive over-simplification, of course.] You tell them the checksum & give them the file [box], anyone later can use the same SHA256 process to 'see though the window' to check the contents are unchanged, without ever 'opening the box'.

Comment: @YisroelTech OK so if I understood it well I just create my zip package and then I check the checksum using your command. Then I may for example share my file with someone else for instance to windows operating system and checksum should be the same correct sińce nothing inside was no changed ?

Comment: Correct, any application/system/command that shows the SHA-256 hash will all show the same checksum for the same file.

Comment: I just see that by changing file name itself doesn’t checksum. It only apply to inner objects.

Comment: Right. Filename and permissions etc. aren't actually part of the file (they're just saved separately by the filesystem in its index of all files) so they don't effect the checksum

Comment: None of this, of course, will prevent someone from simply duplicating your file, working on the copy to produce their own code & if ever challenged, just show you the original file again.